# Can be generated source of VB.NET application framework grabbed somewhere?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, generated-code

I would like to turn off application framework in VB.NET **WinForms** project in order to use [Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setunhandledexceptionmode(v=vs.110).aspx) method which must be injected into **Main()** before UI is initiated.

But after switching it off I'll lose automatic saving of settings and other features. I'm using at least that saving of settings (and who knows what else is in the automatically generated source what I'm relying upon...) So before disabling of application framework I'd like to obtain source code that Visual Studio inserts behind the scenes (app startup, app exit, ...) and make it explicit part of my source code. Is it possible to get that automatically generated code?

Note: I think sources in question can be seen for WPF project but what about WinForms project? Adapt those sources from WPF?

*Even linking to full code for WinForms application framework will help. I'll sort out what is needed for my project.*

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#Microsoft.VisualBasic/ApplicationServices/WindowsFormsApplicationBase.vb,aed47378a860f51d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### A workaround:

Funny enough, in meantime I found* that if app is run ***outside*** the VisualStudio, calling **SetUnhandledExceptionMode() is NOT needed**.

Just handling of *AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException* and *System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException* is enough for proper handling.

Inside VisualStudio, you always get *UnhandledException* but this is still an acceptable compromise – **so application framework can be kept in place**.

*) https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9dbbe3b6-2e92-4a98-be62-28c933a7741e/error-calling-applicationsetunhandledexceptionmode?forum=winforms&prof=required (see **dalkae69**'s reply)